# Using the number I got with barssince() as 'legth'

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Isn't barssince() an integer data type? When I use the value I obtained with "barssince()" in the LENGTH of the MA, it gives an error as you can see in the picture. Why?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BniU9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

`barssince()` returns series integer (value that changes over the bars), but `ta.ema()` require simple integer (constant value).

If `ta.ema()` would be able to accept series value, then the plotted result might be incorrect (same plot, different ema's).

If you actually need series length, then you can use this:
https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#can-i-use-a-variable-length-in-functions